# Does System.out.println() have any other use than printing output to the console?

Tags: java, io, console, println, system.out

I was asked the following question during an interview:

> Does `System.out.println()` have any other use than printing output to the console?

Comment: what do you think? besides that, do you think printing output to a console isn't a worthy purpose?

Comment: It can be used to debug

Comment: Well ... since standard output can be redirected to a file, a pipe, etc, `System.out.println()` can be used to write to those.   Perhaps you need to learn about the capabilities of command shells.  It is relevant to any technical IT job, not just programmer jobs.

Answer (score 3):

#### [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out)

`System.out` is a `static` **object** of type [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html). It holds a reference to the *standard output stream* which is usually the console. Usually, printing to the console is useful when you want to interact or display messages to the user in a console application, log status and error messages to the console. It is very useful for debugging to print out the values of variables, and to check if the program reaches a specific `if-else` branch or loop.

---

#### [`System.err`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#err)

There is also an object called `System.err` which holds a reference to the *standard error stream*. It also usually is the console, the same console that `System.out` holds a reference too. Therefore, you can write:

```
System.err.println("Message");
```

And you would get a message on the console just like you had used `System.out`. But `err` is usually recommended to print out error messages.

---

#### Redirection

Although `System.out` holds a reference to the console, the `System` class provides you a method called [`setOut()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)):

```
public void setOut(PrintStream out)
```

Similarly, there are methods `setErr(PrintStream)` and even a `setIn(InputStream)` which can be used to change `out`, `err` and `in` to reference a different stream, like a file, so you can do something like:

```
PrintStream standardOut = System.out;
PrintStream fileOut = new PrintStream(new File("filename.txt");
System.setOut(fileOut);

System.out.println("Hello World!") // This will output to the file

System.setOut(standardOut); // Reset to the standard output stream
```

---

#### Other methods of `PrintStream`

Other than `println`, `PrintStream` defines methods like [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) and [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) which also allow you to format your input, like you would in a language like C. Both of these methods are identical:

```
int n1 = 10, n2 = 20;
int sum = n1 + n2;
System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d", n1, n2, sum);
System.out.format("%d + %d = %d", n1, n2, sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the statement `System.out.println("xyz")` serves no other purpose than writing the passed string (`xyz`) and a line separator (`System.lineSeparator()`) to the `PrintStream` assigned to `System.out`.

Notice that the console was not mentioned in the above statement. Since it is possible to re-assign the *"standard" output stream* (`System.out`), we can write to places other than the console by executing `System.out.println("xyz")`.

*Here is an example:*

```java
PrintStream fileOut = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"), true);

PrintStream console = System.out; // store current System.out
System.setOut(fileOut);

System.out.println("This will be written to output.txt");
```